# Python HTTP Error - 403 Forbidden

Tags: python-3.x, http-status-code-403

I am trying to get some code to run in Python 3.3.
Here is the code:

```
import urllib.request

html = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.google.com/")

html_code = html.read()
html_code = str(html_code)
sind = html_code.index("<cite class=]\"vurls\">") + len("<cite class=\"vurls\">")
eind = html_code.index("</cite>")
ser1resurl = html_code[sind:eind]
print(ser1resurl)
```

It gives a 403 Forbidden error because of the urllib.request.open(google)

Comment: Works fine for me. It's probably a network issue on your side. However the substring you search is not found.

Comment: Is there a proxy between you and the internet? what do other tools on the box say when opening that Url? I don't know if Python respects certificate authoritiy chains (I seem to recall it doesn't) but check the CACerts are installed as appropriate, just in case